# Python can't recognize command, but CMD can

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I have installed [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) and am trying to call it via Python.

I have added the path to my system Environment Variables and can successfully run the following command via the command prompt:

```
qpdf --decrypt input.pdf output.pdf
```

This runs, no issues.

However, when trying to call via Python (code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40621173/4650297)), I get

> 'qpdf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["cmd", "/c", "qpdf --decrypt input.pdf output.pdf"], shell=True)
# or 
subprocess.run(["qpdf", "--decrypt", "input.pdf", "output.pdf"], shell=True)
# or
subprocess.run(["qpdf --decrypt input.pdf output.pdf"], shell=True)
```

Why can I run this via cmd, but not in Python?

Comment: ensure that you have your python program in the same directory in from which the CMD works .

Comment: It may be that you're using a shell session from before you added `qpdf` to `PATH`. Try running the python from a new session.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) "On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies the default shell. The only time you need to specify shell=True on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a batch file or console-based executable."

Comment: @JMAA - Aha! I had SublimeText open before, during, and after installation of `qpdf`.  I exited out and re-opened and it's not throwing the error anymore.  That was it, a simple fix thankfully :D

Comment: (@JMAA - If you want to turn that in to an answer, go for it and I can the question as Answered)

Comment: @Iguananaut - Ah, thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments:

The problem is that environment variables are only loaded when you launch your executable/shell session/whatever. Here, a directory was added to the `PATH` environment variable, so sublime text needed to be restarted before it could see the updated `PATH`. This isn't specific to sublime, the same would be true if you were running directly from a terminal or another IDE.